# How to express derivative of expectation of maximum in terms of the expectation itself?

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives

Let us assume that we have a random variable $X$.

Is it possible to express
$$ \frac{\partial E[\max(uX+a,0)]}{\partial u}$$
only in terms of $E[X]$ and $a$, where $a$ is a constant ?

I tried different derivations but I can't find an easy solution.

Comment: What is $u$ here?

Comment: Certainly that function is not differantiable everywhere.

Comment: $u$ is just a real number and we want to find the u that maximizes this expectation.

Comment: If $X \equiv 0$, then the function is constant. Now find another random variable $X'$ with $E[X']=0$ but for which the function is not constant. If you can find such an example, it shows that what you want is impossible (why?!).

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed there are plenty of random variables with mean 0 that are not constant. However I do not see the relation with the derivative.